# Are there pet friendly insecticides that kill only spiders?

Tags: pest-control

Is there a insecticide that only kills spiders?  I have  a cat and a dog.  So, I have to be careful what I use.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use spider traps?  Basically a triangular or rectangular pasteboard tube covered with adhesive inside.  Probably safe for pets if they don't chew it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this stuff myself yet but I see [Billy the Exterminator](http://www.aetv.com/billy-the-exterminator/) use  eugenol oil all the time.  It is supposed to be natural and safe.  [EcoSMART](http://www.ecosmart.com/) looks like one brand that sells it but I assume there are many more.

But a quick Google search also turns up more info this stuff that might be worth reading up on: [Darker Side of Eugenol Oil](http://pestcemetery.com/darker-side-eugenol-oil/).